# Difference between comparing two properties and two values in Linq Where clause

Tags: c#, linq

Please consider the following statement:

```
var matches = person.Contacts.Where(c => c.ContactType == searchContact.ContactType).ToList();
```

This will filter all the records with matching ContactType of searchContact object and returns only the filtered Contacts of person.
But without ToList() method call at the end of the Where clause, it will return all the Contacts of person.

Now, consider the following code segment.

```
Dictionary<int, string> colors = new Dictionary<int, string>(){ {1, "red"}, {2, "blue"}, {3, "green"}, {4, "yellow"}, {5, "red"}, {6, "blue"}, {7, "red"} };
var colorSet = colors.Where(c => c.Value == "red");
```

This query will filter only the elements with value "red", even without calling ToList() method.

My question is why this two statements (one that compares values and one that compares properties) behave in a different way without ToList() method call? 
Why this problem does not occur with FirstOrDefault instead of Where clause?

I really appreciate, if anyone can explain the scenario or post some references that I can follow.
Thanks!!

Comment: The results of those operations are not the same. First case you get a List. Second case you get an enumerable.

Comment: Are you sure that first statement will return all the contacts, if you don't call ToList()? With or without ToList(), the result set shouldn't be different, it's result type that differs - with ToList() you get List<Contacts>, without ToList() you get IEnumerable<Contacts>

Comment: Yes, I checked that several times. Adding ToList() solved the problem.  But it's good to make sure that there is no difference between comparing properties vs values. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken. Without calling `ToList()` or another method to force immediate execution, both statements will return an `IQueryable<T>`. Until you iterate over your query variable by using a `foreach` the query variable remains just that.

This article on MSDN should explain things well: [Query Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you are experiencing is called **Deferred Query Execution**.

> In a query that returns a sequence of values, the query variable
>   itself never holds the query results and only stores the query
>   commands. Execution of the query is deferred until the query variable
>   is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop. This is known as
>   deferred execution.

When you use `ToList()` what occurs is known as **Immediate Query Execution**.

> In contrast to the deferred execution of queries that produce a
>   sequence of values, queries that return a singleton value are executed
>   immediately. Some examples of singleton queries are Average, Count,
>   First, and Max. These execute immediately because the query must
>   produce a sequence to calculate the singleton result. You can also
>   force immediate execution. This is useful when you want to cache the
>   results of a query. To force immediate execution of a query that does
>   not produce a singleton value, you can call the ToList method, the
>   ToDictionary method, or the ToArray method on a query or query
>   variable.

These are core behaviors of LINQ.

Comment: Thank you very much Derek!! I had no idea about this behavior before your posted this information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> But without ToList() method call at the end of the Where clause, it will return all the Contacts of person.

No, without `ToList` it will return a query which, when iterated, will yield all of the contacts matching the value you specified to filter on.  Calling `ToList` only materializes that query into the results of that query.  Waiting a while and iterating it later, possibly using some other method of iteration such as `foreach`, will only change the results if the underlying data source (in this case, a database, by the look of thigns) changes its data.

As to your dictionary filter, the same thing applies.  Without calling `ToList` the variable represents *a query to get the data when asked*, not *the results of that query*, which is what you would get by calling `ToList`.

The use of a property versus a field is irrelevant here.  Having said *that*, both queries are using properties, not fields.  Even if one did use a field though, it wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Servy. But I'm wondering even if the use of a property versus a field is irrelevant here, why does the first statement doesn't filter the matching records without calling ToList(). I'm not try to make a point here, but wanna know whether there is anyone who has noticed this behavior before.

Comment: @Watz It *does* do the filtering, even without calling `ToList`.  Or at least, it does do the filtering when you actually iterate the query.  If you think it does not, then you are either not actually iterating this query, you are not properly observing the results, or you are not properly analyzing the results.

Comment: I checked the values inside the output by adding a watch. Two cases showed two different outcomes. I know this seems weird. That's why I wanted to make sure whether there is a difference between these two comparisons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But without ToList() method call at the end of the Where clause, it will return all the Contacts of person.

You are wrong.`ToList` is just forces the iteration and gives you your *filtered elements* as a `List`.`LINQ` uses deferred execution which means until you use `foreach` loop to iterate over items or use `ToList` or `ToArray` methods, it's not executed.So `ToList` doesn't change your items. `Value` is also a property (see `KeyValuePair<T,K>` class), so you are performing a comparison based on property values in both query.There is no difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. I had the same idea about ToList() method. But I don't understand the difference that this method call caused. i.e. without ToList() it returned all the Contacts of person, instead of filtering only the matching Contacts (the condition inside the Where clause).